# How do I create higher auto incremental ID numbers in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a column for ID number that auto increments, but I want to be able to give this number to a customer. Unfortunately MySQL starts the auto-increment at 1. I would like to give the customer that is 5/6 numbers. Is this possible?

Comment: I would recommend not using auto-increment values then. Just generate your own numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable AUTO_INCREMENT=1000000;
```

Then you should insert at least one row, because InnoDB will reset the next auto-increment value to `MAX(id)+1` if you restart MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER TABLE` to accomplish this:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable AUTO_INCREMENT = 100001;
```